# How to HIDE element based on IF statement when onClick is used

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement, hide, show

I need to be able to hide an image that appears when clicking on an option within a select field ONLY if the `value=""` (nothing inside quotes). If the value="some_url" inside the option, then I want the image to show.

I have used the following code to SHOW the image when an option is clicked. But when using onClick, it shows the image even if the option value="".

Here is the Javascript I'm using:

```js
function showImage() {
    document.getElementById('openimg').style.display = 'block';
```

Here is the html:

```
<select name="" >
   <option value="url" onclick="showImage();">Some_option_1</option>
   <option value="">Some_option_2</option>
   <option value="">Some_option_3</option>
 </select>

<a href='url_2'><img src='images/some_img.jpg' id='openimg' style='display:none'></a>
```

I only inserted one onClick command inside one option, just to show that it works. It seems I need an if statement to "show if" or "hide if" along with the onClick command within each option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I would do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showImage()
{
    var choice = document.getElementById('myDropDown').value;
    if(choice.length > 0)
    {
        document.getElementById('openimg').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('openimg').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>

<select id="myDropDown" onchange="showImage()">
<option value="url">Some_option_1</option>
<option value="">Some_option_2</option>
<option value="">Some_option_3</option>
</select>
<a href='url_2'><img src='images/some_img.jpg' id='openimg' style='display:none'></a>
```

Comment: I already have an id and onChange event within the `<select>` for a different event. Can I have more than one id and onChange event within the same element?

Comment: Your <select> element can only have one onchange event.  If you already have an onChange event handler, then you could just call the showImage function above from inside your onChange event handler.  Hope that makes sense

Comment: That may solve the two functions within one onChange event, but I already have another id I must have within the select element, which means I can't use the second id in your suggested code.

Comment: No problem.  In that case, in the showImage function, replace the reference to 'myDropDown' with the id you are already using

Answer (score 0):

Um, are you asking how to use an if or how to determine what is selected?

First of all, use onchange event in the dropdown.

This is the LONGHAND way of doing it for illustration purposes.

```
function onChange(){

    var mySelect = document.getElementById("my-select");
    var selectedValue = "";

    for( var i = 0; i < mySelect.length;i++){
       if( mySelect[i].selected)
         selectedValue = mySelect[i].value;        
    }

    if( selectedValue == "whatever")
    {
           //do something
    }

    if( selectedValue == "ugh")
          // do something else


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will this work if I already have an onChange event inside the `<select>` field? I have multiple javascript codes manipulating other elements in different ways.

Comment: It is more clear to just have the onchange on the select, not on each item. You can skip the loop like the other poster's response with  var choice = document.getElementById('myDropDown').value;

Comment: My problem is that I already have an id in the `<select>` element. I can add a second function within the onChange event, but I can't add another id. Any suggestions?